# Error: This form has expired. Please refresh and try again

Tags: safecracker, error

I am using Channel Form to submit an entry [here](http://mobilearts.org/calendar/submit-event). However, when a user submits the form, they get the following error:

> This form has expired. Please refresh and try again.

The site is running EE 2.8.1.  I reviewed the other posts here with recommended solutions to this problem, but none of the suggestions work including clearing the cache and adding the hidden csrt_token field.

I confirmed that the permissions are set properly in Channel Forms, so I am not sure how to proceed from here and would appreciate any insights for a solution.

Here is the code:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="calendar_events" class="artist" return="calendar/confirmation"}
              <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{csrf_token}">

            <p><label for="title"><span>*Name of Event</span>
                    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" size="50" maxlength="100" onkeyup="liveUrlTitle();">
                    </label>
            </p>

            <p><label for="submitting_organization"><span>*Organization</span>
                <input type="text" name="submitting_organization" id="submitting_organization" value="" maxlength="75" size="50">
                </label>
            </p>

            <p><label for="submitted_by"><span>*Contact - Full Name</span>
                    <input type="text" name="submitted_by" id="submitted_by" value="" size="50" maxlength="100">
                    </label>
            </p>


            <p><label for="contact_phone"><span>*Contact - Phone Number</span>
                <input type="text" name="contact_phone" id="contact_phone" value="" maxlength="75" size="50">
                </label>
            </p>


            <p><label for="submitters_email"><span>*Contact - Email</span>
                <input type="text" name="submitters_email" id="submitters_email" value="" maxlength="75" size="50">
                </label>
            </p>

            <p><span>*Date and Time</span>
                {exp:calendar:date_widget}
            </p>

            <p><label for="event_location"><span>*Event Location</span>
                <input type="text" name="event_location" id="event_location" value="" maxlength="75" size="50">
                </label>
            </p>

            <p><label for="event_address"><span>*Event Address</span>
                <input type="text" name="event_address" id="event_address" value="" maxlength="75" size="50">
                </label>
            </p>

            <label for="event_summary"><span>*Description of Event</span></label>
                    <textarea name="event_summary" rows="5" cols="65" >{event_summary}</textarea>
                <div class="clearer"></div>
            <br />
            <span>Photo (optional)</span>
                {field:event_thumbnail}
                <br />

            <p><label for="admission"><span>*Cost of Admission</span>
                <input type="text" name="admission" id="admission" value="" maxlength="75" size="50">
                </label>
            </p>

<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    {/exp:channel:form}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `{exp:channel:form}` tag automatically adds a CSRF token. Regardless, use your browser developer tools to inspect your form and confirm that a hidden `input` field exists with a CSRF token set for the `value`.

Comment: You are correct, it does automatically add a CSRF token. So I removed the extra one. Unfortunately the problem remains.

Comment: Is there an xid?

Comment: Yes, there is an XID displayed.

Comment: Is the form submitting to exactly the same domain name as the one it's on?

Comment: Yes it is the same domain.